# Why isn't is_main_query() inside pre_get_posts hook returning true while inside the main loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an `index.php` template inside my theme, with a simple while loop to display posts, like so:

```
<section class="c-section overflow-hidden pt-0">
<div class="o-wrapper">
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : $i=0;
?>
        <div class="row col-gutters pt-6">
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <?php $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $cardDate = get_the_date();
                $cardTitle = get_the_title();
                $cardExcerpt = get_excerpt();
                $cardLink = get_the_permalink();
                $cardExternal = get_field('external_article');
                $cardExternalLink = get_field('external_article_link');
                $cardExternalSource = get_field('external_article_source');
                    include(locate_template('_components/card-newsroom.php'));
                $i++;?>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
  <?php endif;?>
</div>
</section>
```

I am trying to use `pre_get_posts` in `functions.php` to modify the number of posts shown, and remove posts of a certain type.

```
function remove_news_posts( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_front_page() && !is_page() && !is_page_template() && !is_search() && !is_feed() && !is_tax() && !is_admin()) :

  $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'key' => 'external_article',
      'value' => 0,
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )
  ));

  $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '6');
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_news_posts', 1000 );
```

However - this doesn't work. The posts per page is not 6, and the meta query doesn't affect the posts shown, either. I have a `category.php` template that's nearly identical, and the `pre_get_posts()` filter does work there. If I remove `$query->is_main_query()` from the `pre_get_posts` `if` statement, it works fine. But then it also affects other queries I do not want affected (like in sidebars).

Why doesn't `is_main_query()` return true when I'd expect it to return true?

Comment: did you tried to `echo 'is in condition'; die()` to check it works or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out! There were two things going on:

1. Template Hierarchy. My index.php file should have really been home.php, the correct template for the posts index page. See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
2. A filtering system was using query_posts(), which also modified the main query. Per the official WordPress docs, query_posts() is not recommended: "This function will completely override the main query and isn’t intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided wherever possible." (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/)

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone out there. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Because in your statement check if not on the front page!

You can replace with:

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() && (is_home() || is_archive())){ ....
```

Comment: I appreciate the response! But it doesn't even work if the statement is like so:

`if ( $query->is_main_query() ) { ...`